# "it was about what managers believed annoyed their workers about each other"

Tags: sentence-construction

Here is a diologue from a passage.

**Rob:**
*The Institute of Management recently questioned 2,000 managers to find out their
pet hates of office workers. Pet hates are the small annoying habits that really irritate someone.*

**Jennifer:**
*So this
survey asked the managers
what annoyed them about their staff?*

**Rob:**
*No, it was about
what managers
believed annoyed
their workers about each
other.*

Well, I couldn not understand the structure of the sentence "it was about
what managers
believed annoyed
their workers about each
other."

Isn't this sentence more grammatically correct  " it was about what managers believes in things which make their workes annoyed each other"

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

The pronoun *it* refers to "the survey".  This sentence tells us what the survey is about.
The pronoun *their* refers to "managers".  They were the managers' workers.

> **The survey** was about [ *what* managers believed ____ annoyed their workers about each other ] .

The bracketed portion is a **free relative clause**.

---

Let's try putting this sentence together:

> **Something** annoyed the workers about each other.

There was something about the workers that annoyed the other workers.
At least, managers believed this was true:

> Managers believed [ **something** annoyed their workers about each other ] .

Now let's **relativize** the clause:

1. We'll pull out the word ***something***, replacing it with the relative pronoun ***what***.
2. We'll move ***what*** to the front of the clause, leaving behind a **gap**.

> [ *what* managers believed [ ____ annoyed their workers about each other ] ]

Now we have a relative clause.  We'll use it as a noun phrase:

> It was about [ *what* managers believed [ ____ annoyed their workers about each other ] ] .

Here, ***what*** has two roles at the same time:

1. It's the subject of the verb ***annoyed***.
2. It's the head of the noun phrase that is the object of the preposition ***about***.

The survey was intended to identify the attributes of workers that annoyed other workers. It was not intended to identify the attributes of workers that annoyed their managers, which is why the sentence began with ***no***.

The original sentence is grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

The phrasing is a bit awkward, to be sure, but I don't think you've got the gist of it with your proposed replacement.

Imagine an office with 3 people: Elvis, Ed, and Mike. Mike manages Elvis and Ed.  From your sample dialog, Jennifer assumes that the survey asked Mike what Ed and Elvis do that Mike found annoying.  Rob clarifies that the survey actually asked Mike what he thinks Ed does that annoys Elvis and what Elvis does that annoys Ed.

As to the grammatical structure, the grammar of the given phrase is correct (if, as I said, a bit awkward), while your replacement has a few issues:

"managers believes" -> singular/plural mismatch; must be "managers believe"

"believe in" -> is used to indicate a conviction that the stated object or idea is real or true;  to "believe in things that make people annoyed" is to hold the position that some unspecified things exist that make people annoyed, which is a position so obviously true as to be not even worth mentioning.

"what managers believe in things" -> this is a statement selecting a subset of managers, not a statement about annoying habits; it is equivalent to (which managers are there that believe this), not (what thing do these managers believe).

"make their workers annoyed each other" -> *each other* is left hanging here; you need a "with" or an "at" to make it grammatical.

A better replacement phrase might be "it was about what managers believe their employees do, that their other employees find annoying."

Comment: Hi Hellion! Thank you so much your help.Now I am sure I understood the passage correctly but still I could not figure out the structure of the sentence I had mentioned before.. I mean is there a deduction in this sentence.. Isnt it supposed to come a different word after the word believed in this sentence? Does it sound natural?

Comment: I got delayed trying to write up how the original sentence worked and then snailplane snuck in with an excellent explanation, so I won't bother trying to top her answer there.

Comment: @snailplane duly noted, and apologies for the mispronounciation.  :-)